# how can i send json data from my controller to view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
   public function getSectionsForClass(Request $request ,$id )
    {
        $section = Section::all()->where('clas_id',$id);
         return  response()->json($section);

    }
```

I need to send this json to my view in table like

```
@foreach($section as $sec)  
     {{$sec->section}}
      {{$sec->capacity}}
        {{$sec->teacher}}
      {{$sec->class}}

  @endforeach
```

This is my ajax code where i have send id and url

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#select_id').change(function(){
             // alert('hello');
             var cid = $(this).val();
             if(cid){
                 $.ajax({
                     dataType: "json",
                     url: 'section/index/'+cid,
                     //data: {'class': cid},
                     type:"GET",
                     success: function(response){
                         console.log ((response));

                     },error: (error) => {
                         console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                   }
              });
             }
         });

     </script>
```

In Route

```
Route::get('admin/section/index/{id}','SectionController@getSectionsForClass');
```

Thanks in advance hope I will get my answer

Answer (score 0):

As per the Laravel Documentation you can directly send the `json` response from your method

> The json method will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to
>   `application/json`, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the
>   `json_encode` PHP function:

```
return response()->json([
    // You can pass your array values here
]);
```

And then you can create dynamic table from your ajax success at append that table in specific id for e.g

```
success: function(response){
         for (var key in response) {
          $('#here_table').append( '<tr><td>' + response[key] +  '</td></tr>' );
          }
 }
```

[Laravel -> Http Responses -> Json Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses)

Comment: thank you but I need a whole ajax and js code to solve my problem. I mean I can do this by making the page reload but I wanted to without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are returning an instance of the Query Builder as a json response. You haven't execute the query yet.

To get the results from your query you need to actually execute the query. Add `get()` at the end:

```
public function getSectionsForClass(Request $request ,$id )
{
    $section = Section::where('clas_id', $id)->get();
 //                                          ^^^^^^^
    return  response()->json($section);
}
```

Of course, this could be better managed in a paginated list in case you have lots of records, but you get the idea.

Comment: I think Section::all() it' s already executing the query and returning a collection. The query should be just Section::where('clas_id', $id)->get();

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I totally missed the `all()` method that he included. Good catch.